# How to fix 'pod update' getting stuck on a private pod?

Tags: cocoapods, dependency-management, podspec

When I try to run 'pod update', execution hangs on the download of my private library:

```
Update all pods
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `Obfuscated-Library` from `https://obfuscated.unfuddle.com/git/obfuscated_mvl/`, branch `develop`
```

I’ve let it hang for about 10 minutes before `Ctrl-C`’ing to cancel it.

What on earth is going on?

Here is some information about my private pod

**Private Library .podspec**

```
#
# Be sure to run `pod spec lint Obfuscated-Library.podspec' to ensure this is a
# valid spec and remove all comments before submitting the spec.
#
# To learn more about the attributes see http://docs.cocoapods.org/specification.html
#
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "Obfuscated-Library"
  s.version      = "0.3.1"
  s.summary      = "A common library for Obfuscated."
  s.description  = <<-DESC
                      A source for common features found in Obfuscated apps.
                      DESC

  s.license      = {
  :type => 'Copyright',
  :text => <<-LICENSE
           Copyright (c) 2013 Obfuscated, Inc. All rights reserved.
           LICENSE
  }
  s.author       = { “Some Guy” => “someguy@gmail.com" }
  s.source       = { :git => "https://obfuscated.unfuddle.com/git/obfuscated_OBl/", :tag => "0.3.1" }

  s.platform     = :ios, '6.0'

  s.source_files =  'OBLibrary/**/*.{h,m}'

  s.resources = ['OBLibrary/**/*.{xib,png,json,ttf}', 'OBLibrary.xcdatamodeld']

  s.ios.resource_bundle = { 'OBCoreData' => 'OBCoreData' }

  s.dependency 'JASidePanels', '~> 1.3.2'
  s.dependency 'iCarousel', '~> 1.7.6'
  s.dependency 'KGModal', '~> 0.0.1'
  s.dependency 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7.1'
  s.dependency 'HockeySDK', '~> 3.5'
  s.dependency 'KDropDownMultipleSelection', '~> 1.0.1'
  s.dependency 'SVPullToRefresh', '~> 0.4.1'
  s.dependency 'FXKeychain', '~> 1.5'
  s.dependency 'PMCalendar', '~> 0.3'
  s.dependency 'RSBarcodes', '~> 0.0.5'
  s.dependency 'IQKeyboardManager', '~> 3.1.1'

  s.frameworks = 'Foundation', 'UIKit', 'QuartzCore', 'CoreLocation', 'MapKit', 'CoreGraphics', 'CoreText'
  s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'Pods/HockeySDK/Vendor/CrashReporter.framework'

  s.requires_arc = true

  s.homepage = "http://www.Obfuscated.com"

end
```

**Private Library Podfile**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, "6.0"

xcodeproj 'OBLibrary.xcodeproj'

pod 'JASidePanels', '~> 1.3.2'
pod 'iCarousel', '~> 1.7.6'
pod 'KGModal', '~> 0.0.1'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7.1'
pod 'HockeySDK', '~> 3.5'
pod 'KDropDownMultipleSelection', '~> 1.0.1'
pod 'SVPullToRefresh', '~> 0.4.1'
pod 'FXKeychain', '~> 1.5'
pod 'PMCalendar', '~> 0.3'
pod 'RSBarcodes', '~> 0.0.5'
pod 'IQKeyboardManager', '~> 3.1.1'
```

**Client App Podfile**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

xcodeproj ‘WL.xcodeproj'

pod ‘Obfuscated-Library', :git => "https://obfuscated.unfuddle.com/git/obfuscated_mvl/", :branch => "develop"
```

Comment: Have you ever find solution on this?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by changing the Podfile to use an ssh authentication git url like this:

`pod 'Obfuscated-Library', :git => "git@obfuscated.unfuddle.com:obfuscated/mvl.git", :branch => "develop"`

I'm not sure why the http method doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the repo URL to one starting with `git://`.

Found in [a discussion of the same/similar issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2481#issuecomment-56541411) in the CocoaPods project on Github.  The issue appears to be a problem with repos on Github Enterprise.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually solved my problem. BTW, in my case it was a repo of a custom forked library at my own account, nothing on GitHub Enterprise or anything.

Answer (score 0):

At times, when working on a large project, modifying HTTPS vs SSH settings isn't possible (firewall, public vs private access). And other steps such as deleting local pods & derived data don't work.

You may cross-check the `pod --version`. Delete pod cache via following commands and try `pod install` afresh.

`` rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
bundle exec pod install ``

Link: [Private Pod update/install stuck at Pre-downloading: "" from "" step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43620853/private-pod-update-install-stuck-at-pre-downloading-from-step)