# Private Pod update/install stuck at Pre-downloading: "" from "" step

Tags: cocoapods, podfile

We have a private git repo that has shared framework for mobile apps, let's call it mobilesdk. Recently a new dev joined the team, and when she is setting up the repo `pod install` & `pod update mobilesdk` are getting stuck at the following step:

```
 Pre-downloading: `mobilesdk` from `https://github.companyurl.com/mobileFramework/mobilesdk.git`, branch `release/0.9`
```

pod inclusion:
`pod 'mobilesdk', :git => "https://github.companyurl.com/mobileframework/mobilesdk.git", :branch => "release/0.9"`

`"pod env"
    CocoaPods : 1.1.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.2.5p319
    RubyGems : 2.4.5.1
        Host : Mac OS X 10.11.6
       Xcode : 8.0 (8A218a)
         Git : git version 2.8.4 (Apple Git-73)`

Answers on related question doesn't help: [How to fix 'pod update' getting stuck on a private pod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072765/how-to-fix-pod-update-getting-stuck-on-a-private-pod)

Tried changing SSH vs HTTPS; It didn't fix it. Also, it's not really an option as `pod install` works for existing devs, and this issue is local to her machine/setup. https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.9/user/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/

How to get past this private-pod install step and debug it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Deleting cocoapods cache fixed the issue**

```
rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods" 
rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/" 
bundle exec pod install
```

Other details:

I took following steps to debug it:

A) Remove unsupported or untested cocoapods gems. Earlier, there were multiple versions of cocoapods on the system. Existing developers are using `v1.2.1`, so removed other versions.

```
pod --version
1.5
1.2.1
1.1.1
..
```

used `gem uninstall cocoapods`.

This didn't fix the issue.

B) Tried `pod repo update`.

C) Removed Cached pods & local pods and did `pod install`, and it completed successfully.

```
rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
bundle exec pod install
```

Found the suggestion here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/568

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because of temporary github.com routing issues: https://github-debug.com/

```sh
git clone https://github.com/github/debug-repo /tmp/debug-repo-http
git clone git@github.com:github/debug-repo /tmp/debug-repo-ssh
ping -c 10 github.com
traceroute github.com
```